# Ruby - proper way to access a query response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

What is the proper way to access objects inside of an Active Record query response? I specifically want to access the value of the `question` key, but I want to be able to use the other values later in my code.

```
from -e:1:in `<main>'irb(main):008:0> poll_data
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Poll id: 1, user_id: 1, question: "(conorao) - Which NFL team do you like the best?", poll_type: "multiple_choice", active: true, created_at: "2017-02-17 21:08:40", updated_at: "2017-02-17 21:08:40">]>
irb(main):009:0> poll_data.class
=> Poll::ActiveRecord_Relation
```

I could not figure out how to access the value associated with the `question` key. So I reformatted the query to `poll_data = Poll.where(user_id: 1, active: true).pluck` and the accessor to `poll_data[0][2]` , but I know this is garbage code.

Comment: `poll_data.first.question`. A `Relation` is a collection-like object. Among others, it has methods `first`, `length` and `to_a`

Comment: Thank you! So is the query response an array that contains individual hash pairs? 
UPDATE: relation - got it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ActiveRecord::Relation` is a rails class that represents zero, one or more rows from your datastore. The simple information you need to know for use it is probably that this class includes the `Enumerable` module.

So, you could call `each`, `first`, `last`, `select` methods and these are just examples. http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html

```
poll_data.each do |item|
  puts item.question
end
```

Comment: So why does
`poll_options_data = PollOption.where(poll_id: poll_data.id)`
`poll_options_data.each do |item| puts item.value end`
Spit out the entire response instead of the values?

Comment: Are you trying that in the console? If so, probably it is printing the value for each element but then you have to know that `each` method returns the enumerable, so you see that printed too. This is not a problem in your code outside the console.

Comment: Yes, that was the result I was seeing in the console. Thank you!

Comment: My pleasure Sir ;)

Answer (score 0):

Where returns ActiveRecord::Relation you can access the first item simply by doing

`poll_data.first.question`, you can loop through the resultset if you want to perform an operation on each Poll, like this

```
poll_data.each do |poll| 
  puts poll.question
end
```

There is also a `.first`, `.second`, `.third` and a `.fifth` for easy retrieval